# How to work with custom user columns in Parse.com and swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am using parse.com to create my swift app backend.

I want to add columns to my user and then refer to the current user's new columns/fields throughout my code.

What is the best way to do this?

When I create my user in my swift code I add the columns

```
func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController!, didSignUpUser user: PFUser!) {
 user["points"] = 0
 user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
  if success == false || error != nil {
  println(error)
 }
}

I tried creating a User class which inherited from PFUser
class User: PFUser {
 var points = 0
}
```

I want to be able to check if the user has points in various controllers. I tried something like this

```
var query = PFUser.query()
 query.whereKey("user", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser().username)
 query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
  if error == nil {
   var user = objects.first? as? User
   if user != nil {
    if user!["points"] as Int == 0 {
     println("You have no points")
    }
   }
  }
}
```

I also tried:

```
var points = PFUser.currentUser()["points"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just refresh the user in background then the user object will contain the new/refresh data/fields.

Answer (score 0):

There is additional field to fill in.
For example, I have one extra field to fill in the password one more time. I make it like this:
In viewDidLoad method:

```
// Change "Additional" to "Confirm password"
[self.signUpView.additionalField setPlaceholder:NSLocalizedString(@"Confirm password",nil)];
```

Remember also to set the position of this field in viewDidLayoutSubviews method

```
 [self.signUpView.additionalField setFrame:CGRectMake(fieldFrame.origin.x + 5.0f,fieldFrame.origin.y + yOffset+ 35.0f,fieldFrame.size.width - 10.0f,                 fieldFrame.size.height)];
```